# How to drag and drop multiple elements with jQuery Drag and Drop (with jQuery 1.4.x)

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

There is a plugin in the jQuery plugins repository, http://plugins.jquery.com/project/multidraggable, that does this for jQuery 1.3.x.

When I use it in 1.4.x (and jQuery UI 1.8.x), I am able to select multiple elements, but when I drag, only one element is dragged.

Can anyone help explain how I could get this working?  Not sure if this is outside the realm of stack overflow, if so, my apologies.

Comment: This is within the realm of stackoverflow, but I bet the solution involves upgrading this plugin or modifying it to work with 1.4.x. If you'll notice, it recommends 1.3.2 for execution. Unless you posted a sizable bounty or someone has seen this issue before and corrected it, you're unlikely to get direct answers.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, can you post bounties on stack overflow?  You mean like a cash payment or something?  I think I could probably persuade my work to consider that...

Comment: ahhh - I see it in the faq.  Sadly, I think I am too reputation poor to offer such a high bounty!! 

Reminds me of whuffie in Down and Out in the Magic Kingdom.  I need to start answering some people's questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below works for jQuery 1.7 (current latest):

https://github.com/someshwara/MultiDraggable

Usage:`$(".className").multiDraggable({ group: $(.className)});`

Drags the group of elements together. Group can also be an array specifying individual elements.

Like:`$("#drag1").multiDraggable({ group: [$("#drag1"),$("#drag2") ]});`